# Migration of custom Default.aspx (Web Template)

Tags: migration, web-template

I am considering to change the Default.aspx (no publishing, no wiki welcome page) via Web Template (for self-service site creation) in SP2013. I am wondering if this would have effect on future migrations. Do those migrate well to out-of-the-box SharePoint templates using out-of-the-box database migration for example? Do web parts get rearranged to fewer zones, or are there some errors occurring etc?